# ColdFusion cflocation token problem Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, coldfusion, cflocation

I'm having an odd issue with cflocation and Chrome. I have the following cflocation in my code after user logs in.

```
<cflocation url="./index.cfm?p=10" addtoken="false">
```

Everything works fine Firefox and IE. When I run it using Chrome, it sets the CFID and CFToken in the URL and do not redirect to the page index.cfm?p=10

If I set the `addToken="true"`, the redirect works; however, every time I click on something in the website it returns to the login page (looks like kicks the session timeout).

Is there any issue with CF tokens and Chrome?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me, make sure your privacy/content settings in chrome match up with the other browsers, and make sure none of your chrome extensions are messing with it.

Comment: It is not just happening with me. If I clean cache, it works, but after a couple days the problem back

Comment: Get rid of the period at the beginning of your URL.

Comment: Removing the period did not fix the problem. I think it is related to cache issue

Comment: You can use the statusCode attribute that will tell the browser what kind of redirect it is... maybe that would reset the cache. The default value is 302.

Comment: I added statuscode="302" addtoken="false". Still the same problem

Comment: Is this still an issue with Chrome?